# React Native : Apple Store app screenshots issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm about to upload my first react native app to the Apple Store, for Play Store I have a few (four actually) 16:9 screenshots, which showcase features of the app, but for Apple Store apparently they are much more stricter and I don't know how to handle all these sizes.

[https://www.apptweak.com/en/aso-blog/app-screenshot-icon-video-guidelines-ios-gp#:~:text=Apple%20allows%20a%20minimum%20of,opportunity%20to%20exhibit%20your%20app](https://www.apptweak.com/en/aso-blog/app-screenshot-icon-video-guidelines-ios-gp#:%7E:text=Apple%20allows%20a%20minimum%20of,opportunity%20to%20exhibit%20your%20app).

For example, according to the link bellow I have to attach atleast two screenshots (portrait AND landscape?) dor each of the sizes listed there, that seems like overkill to me, also what if my app doesn't support landscape mode anyways??
Is there a online generator or tool to convert my four 16:9 screenshots to all these different sizes, like I did with my app icons?

Answer (score 0):

As of posting of this answer, you need to post at minimum 4 screenshots to the store:

- min 2x 6.5" screenshots (vertical) iPhone 12 Pro Max
- min 2x 5.5" screenshots (vertical) iPhone 8 Plus

If you have a simulator, you can start a specific version of iPhone to get those screenshots using xcode

Everything else is optional I believe.